# Looping Divs through a Div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, loops

JQuery noob at it again.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
$(function(){
var fourDivs = $('#window > div');
var doSlide = function (){

        if (fourDivs)
            fourDivs
            .delay(1000)
            .animate({marginLeft: 50})
            .delay(1000)
            .animate({marginLeft: 250})
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut(200)
            .animate({marginLeft: -200})
            .fadeIn(500)


};

doSlide();
setInterval(doSlide, 2000);
```

});

I assume this is an amusing, however poor attempt.

For all the experts out there, do I have the right idea? What would you guys recommend?

How would I get an animated loop as such to continue to cycle through a class of divs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a fiddle. For some reason I find this really funny. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Derp. http://jsfiddle.net/cRkce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using jQuery's `.each()` function:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
function loop () {
    $('#window > div').each(function (index, myDiv) {
        if (myDiv) {
                myDiv
                .delay(1000)
                .animate({marginLeft: 50})
                .delay(1000)
                .animate({marginLeft: 250})
                .delay(500)
                .fadeOut(200)
                .animate({marginLeft: -200})
                .fadeIn(500);
       }

    });

}

setTimeout(loop, 1000);
```

Edit: didnt read your question properly

Comment: I thought about using .each but I assumed that my code was poorly written.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the [jquery api queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/),but I don't know this details.